# jmeter not able to accept parameters?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a weird problem.

I am not able to send request parameters to the `LocalHost` while uploading an image.

After selecting `HTTP request sampler`, I add request parameters, the add a file and parameter name for it. If I don't put parameter name for the image it accepts the request parameters, I put the parameter name for the image, then it doesn't accept the request parameters.

What could be the problem?

PS: I have HTTP cookie manager, HTTP request(for logging in and get the session), then another HTTP request for sending request parameters and image with the parameter name. At last View Results Tree.

Comment: Have you check your log file? is the url request you're sending properly formatted?

Comment: Be sure the request method is a POST.  Have you used an http logger (e.g. fiddler for ie, livehttp for firefox) to examine what happens when you do the upload from your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to format your request is to RECORD the action, and then modify the parameters.  This guarantees several things:

1. You have the correct method (POST / GET / etc)
2. All parameter names are correct (the wrong character case can kill you)
3. All parameters are captured.

Additionally, JMETER has as field at the bottom of the HTTP request for attaching additional files.  It is here that you need to specify the full file path and file type.  This will most likely mirror what you've put into the parameters.